# Symfony 4.0 Translator class not injected to controller

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony4

I got a problem in new symfony 4.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Flight;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use App\Form\FlightType;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class DefaultController
 * @package App\Controller
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * 
     * @Route("/")
     * @Route("/{_locale}/", name="homepage", requirements={"_locale" = "%app.locales%"})
     * 
     * @param Translator $translator
     * @param Request $request
     * 
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function index(Translator $translator, Request $request)
    {
        $translated = $translator->trans('Symfony is great');
```

Error:
Controller "App\Controller\DefaultController::index()" requires that you provide a value for the "$translator" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

Configs:
service.yaml

```
services:    
    _defaults:
        autowire: true    
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false

...
App\Controller\:
    autowire: true       
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

translation.yaml

```
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translator:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks: ['en']
```

Whats wrong? Manual here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

1. bin/console cache:clear did not clear messages cache. Helped just hard remove var/cache folder.
2. I have used Action(TranslatorInterface $translator) for inject to controller action (Probably bug in docs)
3. $translator->trans('id') doesn't work with ids. It work when using trans-unit sourse tag.